# Delphi XE2: Can a form cause all of its child controls to paint themselves offscreen?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, gdi, vcl

I am working with this legacy app that has forms having a TScrollBox containing deeply nested TPanel descendents (up to 8 or so levels of nesting), each hosting controls that can cause the panel to be resized to make room for new child panels with their own controls. *e.g.* the user clicks a radio button, which resizes the panel hosting it to accommodate a new child panel with its own controls, including radio buttons that can cause the *child* to be resized and repopulated in the same manner.

The performance of this app was good until it was modified to use VCL styles. The group doing that work had to abandon the effort when it was found that the themed version might take over a minute to redraw itself after a single click.

It turned out that enabling double-buffering at the form level worked to make the repainting performance acceptable when the user clicks on a control. Scrolling is still a problem however. The controls on the form are not able to paint themselves fast enough to keep up with a user scrolling by rolling the mouse wheel. The scrollbar gets moved, a part of the client area gets redrawn, then the next mouse wheel message gets processed, a little bit of the client gets redrawn, and so on until the user quits rolling the mouse and there's time to redraw the whole thing. The code that does the scrolling looks like this:

```
procedure ScrollControl(Window: TScrollingWinControl; ScrollingUp: boolean; Amount: integer = 40);
var
  Delta: integer;

  // This is needed to tell the child components that they are moving,
  // The TORCombo box, for example, needs to close a dropped down window when it moves.
  // If Delphi had used standard scroll bars, instead of the customized flat ones, this
  // code wouldn't be needed
  procedure SendMoveMessage(Ctrl: TWinControl);
  var
    i: integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 to Ctrl.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Ctrl.Controls[i] is TWinControl then with TWinControl(Ctrl.Controls[i]) do
      begin
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_MOVE, 0, (Top * 65536) + Left);
        SendMoveMessage(TWinControl(Ctrl.Controls[i]));
      end;
    end;
  end;

begin
  Delta := Amount;
  if ScrollingUp then
  begin
    if Window.VertScrollBar.Position < Delta then
      Delta := Window.VertScrollBar.Position;
    Delta := - Delta;
  end
  else
  begin
    if (Window.VertScrollBar.Range - Window.VertScrollBar.Position) < Delta then
      Delta := Window.VertScrollBar.Range - Window.VertScrollBar.Position;
  end;
  if Delta <> 0 then
  begin
    Window.VertScrollBar.Position := Window.VertScrollBar.Position + Delta;
    SendMoveMessage(Window);
  end;
end;
```

What I think I want to do is to (right before the outermost call to `SendMoveMessage`)

1. make a DC for `Window`
2. allocate an offscreen bitmap the size of `Window's` client area
3. arrange for all drawing operations on `Window` and its children to be drawn to the offscreen bitmap
4. Call `SendMoveMessage` and
5. bitblt the offscreen bitmap into `Window's` client area and free the bitmap and DC.

But I cannot see how to do step 3. Is it even possible?

Comment: Sounds like maybe a job for creating some custom `TGraphicalControl` descendants to replace the nested `TPanel`s. The fewer `HWND`s involved, the better the performace will be.

Comment: Perhaps it might make sense to update to a better version of VCL styles, or even better, not use them at all, and have the benefit of correct painting and reasonable performance.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, tragically not an option at the moment. Am I correct in guessing that step 3 in the outline is not something that GDI allows?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the project is a large one and the transition from XE2 to later has been too painful for the team to contemplate. Do later versions of VCL styles have markedly better performance? That might be an argument in favor of finally making the jump.

Comment: Personally I avoid VCL styles like the plague  because I believe in applications having native platform UX. But I appreciate there are other views. I know that the early versions were an utter catastrophy of hugs. As I'm sure you know they were introduced in XE2...... Later versions certainly are better for styles. You can only be sure it will help by trying, at least with a test app the rperos the issue.

Comment: @wades this has nothing to do with GDI itself, but in how Windows paints UI controls using `WM_PAINT` messages to the window's `HDC`. `TWinControl` has a `PaintTo()` method that lets you draw windowed VCL controls to an `HDC` or `TCanvas` you specify. Also, why are you sending `WM_MOVE` messages at all? That is a notification message that Windows sends, you should not be sending it manually, especially if you are not actually moving the controls yourself. For instance, to close a dropped combobox list, there is a `CB_SHOWDROPDOWN` message for that purpose.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the people who decided to scroll the window by using WM_MOVE are long gone... this is an app that dates  to Win95 days. I'm not sure when the feature that I'm hacking at was first released, but the earliest versions of this app were built with Delphi 2. So there is a lot of stuff in there that would definitely be done differently if you were starting with a clean sheet.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `TWinControl.PaintTo` seems like it would be of interest if we could subclass every control that this thing uses, but it's not the quick-and-dirty approach I was hoping for (_i.e._ basically, temporarily replacing the window's HDC). If we were going to invest that level of effort, we'd be more likely to go in the direction you suggested before: a design that does not wind up with so many active HWNDs.